# Realtime Sound Routing...Trigger a Sound with Another Sound

Tags: audio, wav, sampling, dictation

I'm looking for a program that is able to recognize individual audio samples from my computer and reroute them to trigger WAV files from a library.  In my project, it would need to be realtime as the latency would not be a desired result.  I tried using dictation software that would recognize words to trigger opening a file and that's the direction where I want to go, but instead of words I want it to be sounds and it would happen in realtime.  I'm not sure where to go and am just looking for some guidance.  Does anyone have any suggestions of what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

That's a fairly broad question, but I can tell you how I would do it. (Hardly the only way, but where I would start.)

If you're looking for real time input, the Java Sound library (excellent tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/)) allows for that. (Just note that microphone input from a web page is difficult on anything, due to major security concerns, so this would be a desktop application.)

If it needs to be real time, the first thing I would suggest is stream and multithread the hell out of it. I would suggest the Java 8 Stream API, but since you're looking for subsamples that match a specific pattern, then each data point will have to be aware of the state of its neighbors, and that isn't easy with streams.

You will probably want to know if a sound roughly resembles an audio profile, so for that, I would pick a tolerance on just how close you want it to be for a match (remembering that samples may not line up 100% anyway, so "exact" is not an option), and then look up [Hidden Markov Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model). I suggest these because they're what voice recognition software typically uses, and while your sounds may not be voices, it will give you an idea of what has already been done.

You'll also want to maintain a limited list of audio samples in memory. Specifically, you will likely need the most recent data, because an audio signal is a time-variant signal, and you can't get a match from just one point. I wouldn't make it much longer than the longest sample you're looking to recognize, as audio takes up a boatload of memory.

Lastly (for audio), I would recommend picking a standard format for comparison. Make it as good as gets you decent results, and start high. You will want to convert everything to that format before you compare it.

Once you recognize a specific sound, it's basically a Command Pattern. Specific sounds can be mapped, even with a `java.util.HashMap`, to specific files, which (if there are few enough) you might even have pre-loaded.

Lastly, it's worth looking at the [Java Speech API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html). It's not part of the JDK and it's quite dated, but you might get some good advice from its implementation.

This is of course the advice of a Java-preferring programmer, but I imagine that there might be some decent libraries in Python and Ruby to help you as well; and of course there's something in C somewhere. This may sound like a lot, but most of the material is already implemented and ready-to-go.

Hopefully this helps, let's look forward to other answers.